# turning multiple columns/rows into a single column/multiple rows

Tags: sql

Select ColumnX, Column Y, Column Z
from TableA

returns the following -

```
        ColumnX    Column Y    Column Z
Row 1   1111111      2222222       33333333

Row 2   4444444      5555555       66666666

Row 3   6666666      7777777       88888888
```

For variable number of rows

I want to turn the whole lot into a single column (preferably deduplicated, but this isn't essential)

e.g.

```
'Single Column Name'

1111111

2222222

3333333

4444444

5555555

6666666

6666666

7777777

8888888
```

A list of IDs which I can then use to feed another enquiry

How can this be done. It seems much simpler than some of the pivot/unpivot examples - but I can't work it out, nonetheless.
I'm just working with simple SQL plus for Oracle

thanks in advance
NEV

Comment: Please edit your question to make it better readable. However, what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union Queries are your friend.

```
SELECT ColumnX AS ID from TableA
UNION
SELECT ColumnY AS ID from TableA
UNION
SELECT ColumnZ AS ID from TableA
```

Comment: Thanks. I see. Taking all the columns from Table A and renaming them all as the same column in the Results Table.